# Jquery Accordion Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

So the default behavior for JQuery UI Accordion is vertical open and close. What I am after is being able to have the same functionality, but only horizontal rather than vertical. Like a panel on right side of web app that by default is open, but then one can click space on left of div to close and open. Kind of like what is in example c2 here:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137702/Accordion?SearchFor=accordion+horizontal&sp=1

Comment: You can manually code something similar using jQuery. Let me know if you want to look into that or just use a plugin

Comment: While it looks like someone posted something that works, I would be interested in seeing what you are proposing please.

Comment: For example [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nLgCe/) is a project that involved toggling width (and height, but you can take that out). With a little work it could be a simple and usable horizontal tab, but a plugin makes implementation easier

Answer (score 0):

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/

check the above link,it shows a simple horizontal accordion.

since you have only one div/panel.i have modified the jquery to work for one div/panel

```
        <ul id="accordion">
        <li>
        <img src="http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/images/section_1.png" />
             <strong>Section 1 Header</strong><br/>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat  quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
       </li> 
          </ul>
```

CSS:

```
          #accordion {
              list-style: none;
              margin: 30px 0;
              padding: 0;
              height: 200px;
              overflow: hidden;
              background: #7d8d96;}

         #accordion li {
              float: left;                  
              display: block;
              height: 170px;
              width: 50px;
              padding: 15px 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              color: #fff;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              line-height: 1.5em;
              border-left: 1px solid #fff;}

           #accordion li img {
              border: none;
              border-right: 1px solid #fff;
              float: left;
              margin: -15px 15px 0 0;
                   }

           #accordion li.active {
               width: 450px;
             }
```

Jquery:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){     
                 var flag=true;
                 $("#accordion li").click(function(){        
                   if(flag==false)
                    {
                      $(this).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
                       flag=true;
                    }
                     else{
                      $(this).animate({width: "450px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
                        flag=false;
                          }      
                        }); 
            });
```

check this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/5YECg/2/

Comment: Problem with the examples given is that they seem to require multiple panels/divs. Basically I only am trying to open and close one div. Further ideas please? Thanks much.

Comment: @Mark: i have edited the code,for one div/panel.is this what you wanted?.

Comment: I am trying to put what I have in the fiddle below in there. Can you help with that please? the fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/devtech8/XjVym/

Comment: @Mark:you said you have only one div/panel,but it looks like you have more than one div and the fiddle you have given has normal accordion. you want your panel header to have the same ui as normal jquery accordion?.

Comment: if you want the same ui as the normal jquery accordion, you can change your css and image ,and for the arrows, you can add the css class when selected and not selected in jquery. it would be nice if you could get me a fiddle with horizontal accordion,on what you have worked so far, for better understanding.